# Fish can't execute anything on my machine without python3

Tags: fish

I have an issue with my fish shell when using pyenv with Python2 activated:

```
$  pyenv shell 2.7.14
$  ls
pyenv: python3: command not found

The `python3' command exists in these Python versions:
  3.6.4
```

It seems like even when I execute a command as simple as `ls` / `cat` / etc, something is calling Python 3. I never get a similar issue without pyenv removing access to Python 3.

How can I find out what is calling Python 3? I've tried clearing my `config.fish` file, but this problem still occurs

Comment: What is `pyenv` doing to your environment? Does it even support fish?

Comment: Removing access to Python 3 - i.e. I think the same thing would happen if I deleted the Python 3 binary.

Comment: I mean, what is it *supposed* to do? Exactly what in your environment is it supposed to change? Also, what is it? A fish function? What is the output of `type pyenv`?

Comment: pyenv is a tool which allows you to change what links from `python`, `python2`, `python3`. So here, it's removing `python3` as a command that can be run. Then I think _something_ is calling `python3` and failing whenever I run any command. Is there any way of finding out what's calling `python3` whenever I run a command?

Comment: start with `grep -r python ~/.config/fish`

Comment: Through trial & error, I found it's the grc library (https://github.com/garabik/grc). I had greped for python3 in that folder but hadn't found anything. Not sure how I would have found it systematically...

Comment: @Maximilian yup, I just ran into issues setting up virtualenvs for python for use with Neovim, and `grc` was the culprit.

Answer (score -1):

This might be triggered by autocompletion. From the [README](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/blob/master/README.rst) section on optional dependencies:

> - automated completion generation from manual pages requires Python 3.5+
> - the `fish_config` web configuration tool requires Python 3.5+ and a web browser

Comment: It is not. The dependency is required to *generate* completion scripts from man pages. After they are generated they are simply ordinary fish completion scripts that don't execute python. And without python installed the generation will simply be skipped.